# Swift: Autolayout constraints issue. Portrait vs Landscape

Tags: ios, swift

I have stuck with an issue of Autolayout constraints based on screen orientation. For implementing constraints I use Autolayout anchors, override of `traitCollectionDidChange` method and create two function where I setup constraints. Something like that:

```
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    switch (traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass, traitCollection.verticalSizeClass) {

    case (.compact, .compact):
        print("compact-compact")
        setupLandscapeLayout()

    case (.compact, .regular):
        print("compact-regular")
        setupPortraitLayout()

    default: break
    }
}

private func setupPortraitLayout() {                
        myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        myButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

}

private func setupLandscapeLayout() {       
    myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    myButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = false

}
```

So the problem here is constraints which work only one time during change of orientation. Every next try it doesn't work. I also tried to use `view.layoutIfNeeded()` and it didn't help. And even tried to set `isActive=false` and create a new constraint - also unsuccessfully(

So is it possible to set constraints in the way I do or there is another better way how to update constraints for screen orientation programmatically?

Comment: Did you set myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: @Gihan yes, sure) So constraints work in portrait orientation, but when I go to landscape - they doesn't (I mean they use values from portrait)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're duplicating constraints and this makes conflicts so 
Put these 2 constraints in `viewDidLoad` (set bot to 20 or -20 according to current orientation )

```
botCon =  myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
botCon.isActive = true
myButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

//

```
private func setupPortraitLayout() {                
    self.botCon.constant = -20
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
private func setupLandscapeLayout() {  
    self.botCon.constant = 20
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: actually idea now is clear, but your implementation isn't. I mean just putting `botCon` in `viewDidLoad` and access to it using self won't work. For that I see, searching a little bit, a property with array of constraints is created and every new constraint appends to it. But u are right about duplicating and these kind of conflicts